# Usage of tr( ) in Button Titles so on created by the UI Editor

Tags: c++, qt, translation, qt5.4

I understand that using `tr( )` makes it possible to translate your text into any language using `QTranslator Class` for example.

Now how do you do it for button titles , window titles etc. created via the UI Editor rather than by code.

Do I have to set the text of each element containing a title by code to make it work, because obviously I can't just enter `tr( "Hello" );` in the title field of the UI editor.

Ex: `QPushButton.setText( tr( "Hello" ) );`

Or might there be a trick I'm unaware of?

Comment: Why can't you? It's normal to set name while button creating like `some_button  = new QPushButton ( tr("Button name"), this );`

Comment: @AndreyDerevyanko sorry it wasn't clear before. I was talking about the UI Editor not creating buttons via code but rather through the editor

Comment: I can be mistaken, but as I know all user visible strings generated by Designer are automatically wrapped into tr() calls.

Comment: @AndreyDerevyanko would you happen to have a resource that's stating this?

Comment: Can't find now but for every text field in Qt Designer there is a `translatable` property. I believe that it'responsible for tr() wrapping.

Comment: @AndreyDerevyanko That makes sense if you post it as answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the text items you have in your source code you have to wrap it with `tr()`. Qt Designer does it automatically for all the text strings if they have `translatable` property selected (it has to be so by default).

The `lupdate` tool supports C++ source files and Qt Designer .ui files so they will be processed.

Answer (score 0):

You just put `tr("Hello")` and that's it.

Comment: sorry it wasn't clear before. I was talking about the UI Editor not creating buttons via code but rather through the editor